# How to loop into a php object and pull property data

Tags: php

How can i loop into the below php object and pull propery value (name, surname, city, country) if a certain property value (id) is given by me.

```
$users = (object) array(
    'id' => '753',
    'firstname' => 'trevor',
    'lastname' => 'bean',
    'address' => array(
        (object) array(
            'country' => 'Romania'
            'city' => 'Iasi'
        )
    )
)
         (object) array(
    'id' => '754',
    'firstname' => 'ben',
    'lastname' => 'stone',
    'address' => array(
        (object) array(
            'country' => 'Hungary'
            'city' => 'Budapest'
        )
    )
);
```

I have tested:

```
 foreach ($users as $user1) {
        if ($user1->id=== '754') {
          echo $user1->firstname
            break;
        }
    }
```

And it returns `trevor` - the `firstname` of `id 753` instead of the firstname `ben` of the requested `id 754`

Comment: your $users variable won't even compile to begin with, where are you getting your object from? some JSON result or what? ***Perhaps if you give us more information about where your data comes from and how it comes we might be able to give you a simpler solution...***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is invalid and will not compile.
I allowed myself to make some assumptions how to correct it:

```
$users = array( (object)array(
    'id' => '753',
    'firstname' => 'trevor',
    'lastname' => 'bean',
    'address' => array(
         (object)array(
            'country' => 'Romania',
            'city' => 'Iasi'
            )
        )
    ),
    (object)array(
        'id' => '754',
        'firstname' => 'ben',
        'lastname' => 'stone',
        'address' => array(
             (object)array(
                'country' => 'Hungary',
                'city' => 'Budapest'
            )
        )
    )
);

foreach ($users as $user1) {
    if ($user1->id=== '754') {
      echo $user1->firstname;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now it works as you request.

Note that I wrapped your objects with array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want PHP's [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php). It will return the object's accessible (public, in this case), non-static properties in an associative array:

```
foreach (get_object_vars($users) as $user1) {
    if ($user1->id=== '754') {
        echo $user1->firstname;
        break;
    }
}
```

You'll also want to fix the multiple places where you have missing `,`s and `;`s.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP has some obvious syntax errors (missing `;` and `,`) and I think you want the `$users` variable to be an array of user objects, not an object. Your code should probably look something like this:

```
$users = array(
    (object) array(
        'id' => '753',
        'firstname' => 'trevor',
        'lastname' => 'bean',
        'address' => array(
            (object) array(
                'country' => 'Romania',
                'city' => 'Iasi'
            )
        )
    ),
    (object) array(
        'id' => '754',
        'firstname' => 'ben',
        'lastname' => 'stone',
        'address' => array(
            (object) array(
                'country' => 'Hungary',
                'city' => 'Budapest'
            )
        )
    )
);

foreach ($users as $user1) {
    if ($user1->id=== '754') {
        echo $user1->firstname;
        break;
    }
}
```

And it retuns the `ben` user as expected: